# Both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu not booting after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I had installed Windows 8.1 in my Dell Inspiron 5521 in Legacy Mode. I then tried installing Ubuntu 14.04. The installation was successful. But after rebooting, I was unable to boot into any OS. While booting windows, "A disk read error ....." appears. Can't boot into Ubuntu too. This is my boot-repair paste.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7864978/
Hope I'll get the issue resolved
Here's my gparted screenshot 
[image]

Comment: You have dynamic partitions which do not work with Linux. That is what happens if you attempt to create more than the 4 allowed primary partitions with MBR(msdos) partition using the Windows partition tools. Only use Windows to shrink a NTFS system partition not to create new partitions. Windows also has to have boot flag on its bootable primary partition. You have it on the extended partition which is now sda1.  If both are new installs it would be easier just to start over. You can convert dynamic back to basic with some third party tools.

Comment: So, the better option is to reinstall windows, then Ubuntu??

Comment: Yes and only use Windows partition tools to shrink the Windows NTFS partition, but not create new partitions. It cannot create Linux partitions anyway. And immediately reboot to make sure it runs chkdsk and makes repairs for its new size. Also make sure fast boot is off. With UEFI and gpt partitions you do not have the 4 primary partition limit that MBR has.

Comment: @oldfred When i try installing Windows 8 via legacy, it doesn't even show up. Through UEFI, it shows up but shows no drives.

Comment: I think some Windows tools also do not work with dynamic partitions, so you may have to undo those first. If installing Windows and Ubuntu be sure to install both in BIOS mode or both in UEFI mode.